# Boto3 shows ConnectionReset Error

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask, boto, boto3

I added a db.session.close() to every function that does a query. Looking up the error also showed me that others had this issue because of the lost connection to S3. Locally it works pretty well. However running the same on a Ubuntu server with mod_wsgi and Apache2 shows the following error:

```
185.27.213.237 - - [17/Sep/2017 16:31:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
185.27.213.237 - - [17/Sep/2017 16:31:39] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
185.27.213.237 - - [17/Sep/2017 16:31:50] "GET /space/user HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

From the Apache logs:

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 1456:tid 139792612300544] ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

The first line was me opening the login route. After logging in with the correct credentials it shows the 302 error. In the following I post my login route and the site that is redirected to after a successful login. I'm using sqlite3 since I only have a couple of user.

```
#Login
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = LoginForm()

    try:
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
            if user:
                if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                    login_user(user, remember=False)
                    return redirect(url_for('showspace', spacename=user.username))
            return render_template('login.html', form=form, ermsg="Invalid credentials")
        return render_template('login.html', form=form)
    except Exception as ermsg:
        db.session.rollback()
        print(ermsg)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    finally:
        db.session.close()

#Dashboard new
@app.route('/space/<spacename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def showspace(spacename):
    try:
        selectedspace=spacename
        spacelist = Space.query.filter(Space.owner.any(id=current_user.id)).all()
        hasaccess = User.query.join(User.spaces).filter(User.username==current_user.username, Space.name==selectedspace).first()
        if hasaccess != None:
            conn = boto3.resource('s3')
            mybucket = conn.Bucket(selectedspace)
            return render_template('dashboard.html', spaces=spacelist, filelist=mybucket.objects.all(), name=current_user.username, selectedspace=selectedspace)
        else:
            return "You don't have permission to view this space!"
    except:
        db.session.rollback()
        return 'Something went wrong'
    finally:
        db.session.close()
```

Comment: The db connection will not be closed since the finally is not run because of an earlier `return`.

Comment: I think it has something to do with Boto3. I have already edited my question. It's still good to know that the finally isn't even executed. I will add db.session.close() at the end of every try block. Thank you.

Comment: @KlausD.: That is not true. The `finally` block will run regardless of the `return`. [Here's the documentation.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions)

Comment: @ZachGates I wondering how that should work, continuing and returning at the same time.

Comment: @user3080315: A `finally` block is perfectly good way to close the session. According to the documentation: ["In real world applications, the finally clause is useful for releasing external resources (such as files or network connections), regardless of whether the use of the resource was successful."](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions).

Answer (score 0):

It would be so much cleaner if you write a decorator and execute your methods inside a database session. Like so

```
def db_session():
    def wrapper(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            # Executing the handler inside a db context
            with Session as session:
                try:
                    return func(session, *args, **kwargs)
                except:
                    session.rollback()

@app.route('/space/<spacename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
@db_session()
def showspace(session, spacename):
    # your code
```

Comment: It is not true that the `finally` suite will not execute. From the docs: ["The finally clause is also executed “on the way out” when any other clause of the try statement is left via a break, continue or return statement."](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions).

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy. I think you posted the vanilla SQLAlchemy. Could you translate me that to Flask-SQLAlchemy to be sure I'm not causing even more issues.

Comment: does db.session have an `__enter__` method?